# How do you remove noise to detect just the human voice?

Tags: sound, signal-processing

How do you detect different sound frequencies and cut off parts in an audio file? Among instruments, how do you pick up the human voice?

Comment: Wasn't this question just posted and migrated to Signal Processing?

Comment: @s0rce could you post the URL ?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov [This was the original question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15254/5). I migrated it, but the OP deleted it and reasked it here again...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)`

Comment: Do you know what type of noise has been added, periodic, narrow band, wide band;   white, pink etc?

Comment: In 2021, try [Demucs](https://colab.research.google.com/github/dvschultz/ml-art-colabs/blob/master/Demucs.ipynb)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

A lot depends on your specific data. But if the noise is far from voice in frequency domain there is a simple brute-force trick of cutting off/out "bad" frequencies using wavelets. Let's import some sample recording:

```
voice = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo11ReturnSafely"}]
```

[image]

`WaveletScalogram` is great for visualizing voice versus noise features:

```
cwt = ContinuousWaveletTransform[voice, GaborWavelet[6]];
WaveletScalogram[cwt, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

Voice is more rich and irregular in structure, noise is more monotonic and repetitive. So now based on the visual we can formulate a logical condition to cut out the noisy octaves (numbers on vertical axes):

```
cwtCUT = WaveletMapIndexed[#1 0.0 &, cwt, {u_ /; u >= 6 && u < 9, _}];
WaveletScalogram[cwtCUT, ColorFunction ->"AvocadoColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

This is pretty brutal, like a surgery that cuts out good stuff too, because in this cases some voice frequencies blend with noise and we lost them. But it roughly works - signal is cleaner. You can hear how many background noises were suppressed (a few still stay though) - use headphones or good speakers. If in your cases noise is even further from voice in frequency domain - it will work much better.

```
InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[cwtCUT]
```

[image]

Comment: How did you make the decision on what was and wasn't noise?

Comment: @rcollyer I gave some explanation under `WaveletScalogram` image. Voice has rich irregular structure. Noise is monotonic and repetitive.

Comment: @NasserM.Abbasi Thanks! I corrected the code, should work now.

Comment: Maybe I should have read it ... :P

Answer (score 14):

What you need is [`BandpassFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BandpassFilter.html), which is new in version 9. Assuming your audio is sampled at 22400 Hz, you can do:

```
BandpassFilter[data, {60 π, 180 π}, SampleRate -> 22400]
```

to filter it to between 60-180 Hz.

Comment: This works for `SampleSoundList`, so for `voice` above, this would be done: `Sound[BandpassFilter[voice[[1]], {60 π, 180 π}, SampleRate -> 22400]]`. It did not work as well as the wavelet based denoising by @Vitaliy Kaurov

Comment: @ubpdqn You'll have to filter the correct band for the sound sample that Vitaliy used. I was addressing OP's question where they wanted to filter their data (not shared) between 60 and 180 Hz.

Comment: @rm-rf thank you for the clarification

Comment: Should that be BandpassFilter[data, {2 π 60, 2 π 180}, SampleRate -> 22400] for radian frequencies? That is, a coefficient of 2 π rather than π.

Comment: @david Maybe... I wrote this answer _before_ version 9 was actually released (going just by the docs which rolled out early). I'll test it with an example edit it later today with some more info.

Comment: @Nasser M. Abbasi: For several versions, including 9, the entire set of Documentation Center pages have been put on-line as soon as the software was released.

Answer (score 13):

About a year ago,I saw a demo in *Labview* that can detect the voice of killer whale in a setting of the sound of seawater.

[image: This image I serched from the Internet because I forgot where to find this demo.]

I want to try the similar thing in *Mathematica*.
Based upon [Vitaliy Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov)'s approach:

```
voice = ExampleData[{"Sound", "Apollo11ReturnSafely"}];
data = voice[[1, 1, 1]]; r = voice[[1, 2]];
cwt = ContinuousWaveletTransform[data, 
GaborWavelet[6]];(*If you set cwt=ContinuousWaveletTransform[data,GaborWavelet[6],{Automatic,8}];
you will get more accurate result.But you must re-extract the interest region*)
WaveletScalogram[cwt, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors", ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

It gives the the scalogram of the wave.

> Then you can use mma graph tools to describe your outline.
>
> Firstly, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to open the graph tools.
>
> Secondly, press the button in the lower right corner.
>
> [image]
>
> Thirdly, you can get the coordinates(use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>).
>
> My data is the following result
>
> ```
> test = {{7183, 40.14}, {7309, 39.89}, {7771, 39.77}, {7939, 39.64}, {8065, 39.39}, {8863, 38.64}, {9913, 37.15}, {1.067*^4, 35.9}, {1.096*^4, 35.65}, {1.13*^4, 35.27}, {1.163*^4, 35.15}, {1.201*^4, 35.02}, {1.247*^4, 35.02}, {1.306*^4, 35.02}, {1.369*^4, 35.27}, {1.428*^4, 35.65}, {1.47*^4, 35.9}, {1.495*^4, 36.15}, {1.52*^4, 36.4}, {1.541*^4, 36.77}, {1.587*^4, 37.27}, {1.629*^4, 37.64}, {1.671*^4, 38.02}, {1.726*^4, 38.14}, {1.789*^4, 38.27}, {1.873*^4, 38.27}, {1.957*^4, 38.27}, {2.02*^4, 38.02}, {2.062*^4, 38.02}, {2.083*^4, 38.02}, {2.104*^4, 38.14}, {2.129*^4, 38.14}, {2.184*^4, 38.14}, {2.238*^4, 37.77}, {2.276*^4, 37.39}, {2.314*^4, 37.02}, {2.343*^4, 36.65}, {2.373*^4, 36.4}, {2.41*^4, 35.77}, {2.427*^4, 35.52}, {2.431*^4, 35.02}, {2.415*^4, 33.53}, {2.402*^4, 32.9}, {2.373*^4, 32.53}, {2.322*^4, 32.28}, {2.314*^4, 32.15}, {2.259*^4, 32.15}, {2.217*^4, 32.15}, {2.196*^4, 32.03}, {2.179*^4, 32.15}, {2.163*^4, 31.91}, {2.121*^4, 31.53}, {2.104*^4,31.16}, {2.066*^4, 30.91}, {2.033*^4, 30.66}, {1.999*^4, 30.53}, {1.961*^4, 30.53}, {1.911*^4, 30.53}, {1.852*^4, 30.53}, {1.81*^4, 30.53}, {1.751*^4, 30.66}, {1.709*^4, 30.91}, {1.671*^4, 30.91}, {1.646*^4, 31.03}, {1.625*^4, 31.03}, {1.6*^4, 31.03}, {1.579*^4, 30.91}, {1.562*^4, 30.66}, {1.537*^4, 30.16}, {1.512*^4, 29.91}, {1.495*^4, 29.66}, {1.478*^4, 29.53}, {1.449*^4, 29.41}, {1.394*^4, 29.28}, {1.357*^4, 29.28}, {1.31*^4, 29.41}, {1.256*^4, 29.66}, {1.214*^4, 29.78}, {1.176*^4, 29.78}, {1.142*^4, 29.78}, {1.088*^4, 29.78}, {1.046*^4, 29.91}, {1.021*^4, 29.91}, {9913, 29.78}, {9745, 29.53}, {9493, 29.28}, {9241, 28.91}, {8947, 28.66}, {8737, 28.29}, {8527, 27.91}, {8317,     27.54}, {8065, 27.16}, {7855, 26.66}, {7603, 26.04}, {7267, 25.54}, {6973, 24.92}, {6806, 24.42}, {6554, 24.04}, {6344, 23.67}, {6176, 23.42}, {6050, 23.3}, {5840, 23.17}, {5714, 23.17}, {5672, 23.67}, {5588, 24.42}, {5546, 25.29}, {5546,     26.54}, {5546, 27.66}, {5546, 28.41}, {5546, 29.16}, {5588, 30.16}, {5630, 31.16}, {5630, 31.91}, {5672, 32.78}, {5672, 33.53}, {5672, 34.15}, {5672, 34.77}, {5672, 35.52}, {5714, 36.27}, {5714, 36.77}, {5714, 37.39}, {5714, 37.77}, {5756, 38.02}, {5756, 38.39}, {5840, 38.77}, {6008, 39.39}, {6092,     39.52}, {6176, 39.64}, {6302, 39.89}, {6428, 39.89}, {6554, 40.14}, {6638, 40.14}, {6764, 40.14}, {6848, 40.14}};
> ListPlot@test
> ```

Then I define a function to transform the coordinates to the coordinates in `WaveletScalogram`:

```
g[{x_, y_}] := 
Module[{a = 
 Floor[(cwt["Octaves"] + 1) - y/cwt["Voices"], 
  1./cwt["Voices"]]}, {x, {Floor[a], 
 Floor[(a - Floor[a])*cwt["Voices"]] + 1}}];
```

In addition, I define a function to smoothen the coordinates:

```
smooth[lis_] := 1/3*(Total /@ Partition[RotateRight@lis, 3, 1, 1])
```

And

```
smoothtestdata = smooth@test; {ymin, ymax} = 
Through[{Ceiling@Min@# &, Floor@Max@# &}[smoothtestdata[[All, 2]]]];
WaveletCoordinate = g /@ (Round@
Module[{gra}, 
 gra = ListLinePlot[Append[smoothtestdata, smoothtestdata[[1]]], 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y}, y], 
   Mesh -> {Range[ymin, ymax, 1]}];
 Cases[Normal@gra, Point[ptlist_] :> ptlist, Infinity] // 
  SortBy[#, Last] &])
```

> I get the result:
>
> ```
> {{5638, {8, 1}}, {6541, {8, 1}}, {7035, {7, 4}}, {5578, {7, 4}}, {5552, {7, 3}}, {7534, {7, 3}}, {5546, {7, 2}}, {8022, {7, 2}}, {8576, {7, 1}}, {5546, {7, 1}}, {5556, {6, 4}}, {9273, {6, 4}}, {5583, {6, 3}}, {15207, {6, 3}}, {16069, {6, 2}}, {16414, {6, 2}}, {20768, {6, 2}}, {5614, {6, 2}}, {5645, {6, 1}}, {21748, {6, 1}}, {23970, {5, 4}}, {5663, {5, 4}}, {24177, {5, 3}}, {5672, {5, 3}}, {5676, {5, 2}}, {24236, {5, 2}}, {5696, {5, 1}}, {23957, {5, 1}}, {14766, {5, 1}}, {10686, {5, 1}}, {5714, {4, 4}}, {15657, {4, 4}}, {23130, {4, 4}}, {9977, {4, 4}}, {9241, {4, 3}}, {5739, {4, 3}}, {16923, {4, 3}}, {21869, {4, 3}}, {8466, {4, 2}}, {5913, {4, 2}}, {6464, {4, 1}}, {7255, {4, 1}}}
> ```
>
> The first element of each sublist is time (Surely, I have not considered the `SampleRate` now), the second is coordinate in wavelet (`{Octaves,Voices}`)

In order to detect the interest region,I define a function.

```
f[lis_, pos_] := 
Module[{poslen = Length@pos, temp}, 
temp = ReplacePart[lis, i_ /; (i < pos[[1]]) -> 0];
Do[temp = ReplacePart[temp, 
 i_ /; (pos[[index]] < i < pos[[index + 1]]) -> 0], {index, 2, poslen - 2, 2}];
temp = ReplacePart[temp, i_ /; (i > pos[[poslen]]) -> 0]; temp]
```

Finally, set the irrelevant region to zero:

```
Module[{temp, tempwavelet = cwt},
Do[temp = Transpose[GatherBy[WaveletCoordinate, Last][[i]]]; 
tempwavelet = WaveletMapIndexed[f[#, Sort@temp[[1]]] &, tempwavelet, 
temp[[2, 1]]],
{i, 1, Length@GatherBy[WaveletCoordinate, Last]}]; 
tempwavelet = 
WaveletMapIndexed[0.*# &, tempwavelet, 
Except[Alternatives @@ WaveletCoordinate[[All, 2]]]]; tempwavelet]
WaveletScalogram[%, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors",  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

If we transform the data to sound:

```
SampledSoundList[InverseContinuousWaveletTransform[%%], r] // Sound
```

we get:

[image]

You can hear the human voice more clearly! :)

*About the function f:*
Think about the following graph:

[image]

If the orange region is data region,the green region is my interest,I want to extract the octave 2 and voice 1,I can use the code:

```
f[Range[10], {1, 6}](*Because my interest time is 1-6*)
(*result: {1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,0}*)
```

Extract the octave 3 and voice 3:

```
f[Range[10], {4, 8}](*Because my interest time is 4-8*)
(*result: {0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,0,0}*)
```

Extract the octave 3 and voice 4:

```
f[Range[10], {5,7}](*Because my interest time is 5-7*)
(*result: {0,0,0,0,5,6,7,0,0,0}*)
```

So If combine this function and WaveletMapIndexed,we can extract the data.

*Let me guess,If we don't extract by hand,otherwise,use the picture processing to get the outline and remove the noise color from the voice color,What's like?*

Comment: I tried to improve the format and expression, but since I'm not familiar with this issue, what I can do is quite limited and I might have made mistakes, so feel free to roll back if you don't like my edit.

Comment: Thank you.more beautiful than ever.