# Bandpassing EEG's using Mathematica's Bandpass Function

Tags: signal-processing

Let's say we have an EEG signal approximated using a fractional Brownian motion:

```
EEG[hurst_,t_low,thigh_,tinc_]=RandomFunction[
 FractionalBrownianMotionProcess[hurst], {tlow, thigh, tinc}, 1]
```

for some parameters hurst_, tlow_, thigh_, tinc_.

The literature on EEG's state that alpha waves are obtained by using a bandpassing filter in the range 14-40 Hz, more or less...

```
data = EEG[0.4,0,1,0.01]
BandpassFilter[Flatten[data[[2, 1]]], {0.14, 0.40}];
```

My question is with regards to the BandpassFilter parameters. Does choosing 0.14 and 0.40 effectively yield the 14-40Hz range? Basically, what are the units of the BandpassFilter function in Mathematica

Comment: You need a factor of `π` and also need to mention the `SampleRate`. See my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15275/5) for an example.